# D3JS : Create distinct arc paths

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to draw arcs corresponding to data. [Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/U4jYlnBTZhGiVrN6zSiO?p=preview)

Actually there are two numbers in the data. Whenever I'm trying to create the two arcs, they are merging together.

```
var pi = Math.PI, arcRadius = 55, arcThickness = 2;
var gaugeData = [32, 57];
var svg = d3.select('.circles').append('svg');

var arcFunc = d3.svg.arc()
    .innerRadius(55)
    .outerRadius(57)
    .startAngle(0)
    .endAngle(function(d) { return d * (pi /180); });

svg.attr("width", "400").attr("height", "400")
    .selectAll('path').data(gaugeData).enter().append('path')
    .attr('d', function(d) { return arcFunc(d); })
    .attr('fill', '#555')
    .attr('cx', function(d, i) { return i * 100 + 30; })
    .attr('cy', function(){ return 50; })
    .attr("transform", "translate(200,200)");
```

The arcs would be like:

[image]

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The two arcs share the same `startAngle` so of course they overlap.  What is your desired output?

Comment: @Mark I want to have the arcs to come side by side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that gaugeData is the degree value for the total sweep of your arc.  So, the first step is to d3ify your data by creating an array of start/stop angles. Then the drawing becomes easy:

```js
var pi = Math.PI, arcRadius = 55, arcThickness = 2;
var gaugeData = [32, 57, 180];
var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg');

var data = gaugeData.map(function(d,i){
  var start = 0;
  for (var j = 0; j < i; j++){
    start += gaugeData[j];  // start angle value is the sum of all the sweeps before it
  }
  var end = start + d; // end angle is the start + sweep
  return {
    start: start,
    end: end
  };
});

var colors = d3.scale.category10();

var arcFunc = d3.svg.arc()
    .innerRadius(55)
    .outerRadius(57)
    .startAngle(function(d) { return d.start * (pi /180); })
    .endAngle(function(d) { return d.end * (pi /180); });

svg.attr("width", "400").attr("height", "400")
    .selectAll('path').data(data).enter().append('path')
    .attr('d', function(d) { return arcFunc(d); })
    .attr('fill', function(d,i){ return colors(i); })
    .attr("transform", "translate(200,200)");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

---

**EDITS For Comments**

Putting the arcs side-by-side is a lot easier, just change the `transform` for each one.  Also note, that `cx` and `cy` are not valid for a `path`:

```js
var pi = Math.PI, arcRadius = 55, arcThickness = 2;
var gaugeData = [32, 57, 180];
var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg');

var colors = d3.scale.category10();

var arcFunc = d3.svg.arc()
    .innerRadius(55)
    .outerRadius(57)
    .startAngle(function(d) { return 0; })
    .endAngle(function(d) { return d * (pi /180); });

svg.attr("width", "400").attr("height", "400")
    .selectAll('path').data(gaugeData).enter().append('path')
    .attr('d', function(d) { return arcFunc(d); })
    .attr('fill', function(d,i){ return colors(i); })
    .attr("transform", function(d,i){
         return "translate("+ ((i * 75) + 10) + ",75)";
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. But I was looking for something like the picture attached to the description.

Comment: @ArnabDas, see new answer above.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I missed the transform part.